# Geometry problem boils down to finding a closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^{k}{\arctan{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}}$

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, products

I was solving the following problem:

"Find $\angle A + \angle B + \angle C$ in the figure below, assuming the three shapes are squares."
[image: 1]]
And I found a beautiful one-liner using complex numbers:

$(1+i)(2+i)(3+i)=10i$, so $\angle A + \angle B + \angle C = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Now, I thought, what if I want to generalize? What if, instead of three squares, there were $2018$ squares? What would the sum of the angles be then? Could I make a formula for $k$ squares?

Essentially, the question boiled down to finding a closed form for the argument of the complex number

$$\prod_{n=1}^{k}{(n+i)}=\prod_{n=1}^{k}{\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}\right)e^{i\cot^{-1}{n}}}$$

This we can break into two parts, finding a closed form for
$$\prod_{n=1}^{k}{(n^2+1)}$$
and
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}{\cot^{-1}{n}}$$

This I don't know how to solve.

Comment: It seems you summed under the square root -- that would work if the square root were a logarithm, but it doesn't work for square roots. You can check that your result doesn't give the right values for the first few values of $k$. (Speaking of which, the products and summations run to $k$, whereas $n$ is just the summation index, so the free variable in the results should be $k$, not $n$.)

Comment: Oops, it seems that I mixed up my products and summations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With CAS help:

$$\sum _{n=1}^k \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\\\int \left(\sum _{n=1}^k \frac{\partial }{\partial a}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)\right) \, da=\\\int \left(\sum _{n=1}^k \frac{n}{a^2+n^2}\right) \,
   da=\\\int \frac{1}{2} \left(-H_{-i a}-H_{i a}+H_{-i a+k}+H_{i a+k}\right) \,
   da=\\-\frac{1}{2} i (\text{log$\Gamma $}(1-i a)-\text{log$\Gamma $}(1+i a)-\text{log$\Gamma
   $}(1-i a+k)+\text{log$\Gamma $}(1+i a+k))+C$$

where $a=1$ and $C=0$ then:

$$\color{blue}{\sum _{n=1}^k \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=-\frac{1}{2} i (\text{log$\Gamma
   $}(1-i)-\text{log$\Gamma $}(1+i)-\text{log$\Gamma $}((1-i)+k)+\text{log$\Gamma
   $}((1+i)+k))}$$

Where: $H_{i a}$ is [harmonic number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html) and $\text{log$\Gamma $}(1-i)$ is  [logarithm of the gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogGammaFunction.html)

MMA code:

```
HoldForm[Sum[ArcTan[1/n], {n, 1, k}] == -(1/2)
I (LogGamma[1 - I] - LogGamma[1 + I] - LogGamma[(1 - I) + k] + LogGamma[(1 + I) + k])] // TeXForm
```

Comment: An integral sign is missing on the second line. By the way, great answer!

Comment: Moreover, I don’t think that $C=0$. Consider the case $a=0$.

Comment: @Szeto. Case is only $a=1$,there are No others cases. `:)`

Comment: cute starting point ! (+1).  Now use the fact that $\Gamma (\tilde z) = \tilde \Gamma (z)$ to simplify a further step and reach to the same conclusion as in my answer : $Im(ln(\Gamma(1+i+k) / \Gamma(1+i)))$

Answer (score 3):

Playing around with Wolfy suggests that
$s(n)
=\sum_{k=1}^n \arctan(1/k)
=\frac{3\pi}{4}-\frac12\arctan(g(n))
$
where 
$g(n)$ is an increasingly complicated fraction.

Some values are
$g(4) = 15/8,
g(5) = 140/71,
g(6) = 2848/7665,
g(7) = 14697/203896
$.

To get a recurrence for
$g(n)$,

$\begin{array}\\
s(n+1)-s(n)
&=\arctan(1/(n+1))\\
&=(\frac{3\pi}{4}-\frac12\arctan(g(n+1)))-(\frac{3\pi}{4}-\frac12\arctan(g(n)))\\
&=\frac12(\arctan(g(n))-\arctan(g(n+1))\\
\end{array}
$

so,
using
$\arctan(x)\pm\arctan(y)
=\arctan(\frac{x\pm y}{1\mp xy})
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\arctan(g(n+1))
&=\arctan(g(n))-2\arctan(1/(n+1))\\
&=\arctan(g(n))-\arctan(\frac{2/(n+1)}{1-1/(n+1)^2})\\
&=\arctan(g(n))-\arctan(\frac{2(n+1)}{(n+1)^2-1})\\
&=\arctan(g(n))-\arctan(\frac{2(n+1)}{n^2+2n})\\
&=\arctan(\frac{g(n)-\frac{2(n+1)}{n^2+2n}}{1+g(n)\frac{2(n+1)}{n^2+2n}})\\
&<\arctan(g(n)-\frac{2}{n+1})\\
\end{array}
$

so,
assuming that
the proper branch of 
arctan is taken,
$g(n+1)
=\frac{g(n)-\frac{2(n+1)}{n^2+2n}}{1+g(n)\frac{2(n+1)}{n^2+2n}}
\lt g(n)-\frac{2}{n+1}
$.

Since $\sum 1/n$ diverges,
this shows that
exentually
$g(n) < 0$.
At this point the
next branch of
arctan has to be taken.

For example,
Wolfy calculates that
$s(20)
=\frac{5 π}{4} - \frac12 \arctan(\frac{47183650393321137025}{17864397263976449928})
$
and
$s(40)
=\frac{5π}{4} + \frac12 \arctan(\frac{41279370979134545450499387615832498927444174194743607}{269197868658553203529942799672226208517623565372926024})
$.

I'll leave it at this.

Comment: Sadly no matches for fraction on OEIS.

Answer (score 2):

We have that
$$
\prod\limits_{1\, \le \,n\, \le \,k} {\left( {i + n} \right)}  = {1 \over i}\prod\limits_{0\, \le \,n\, \le \,k} {\left( {i + n} \right)}
  = {1 \over i}i^{\,\overline {\,k + 1\,} }  = \left( {1 + i} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } 
 = {{\Gamma \left( {1 + i + k} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {1 + i} \right)}} = k!\left( \matrix{
  i + k \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)
$$
where $x^{\,\overline {\,k\,} }  = {{\Gamma (x + k)} \over {\Gamma (x)}}$ denotes the [Rising Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) 
and $x^{\,\underline {\,k\,} }  = \left( {x - k + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } $ the [Falling Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).
By means of the expression through The Gamma Function, they are defined as meromorphic 
functions even for complex $x$ and $k$.

Then
$$
\ln \left( {z^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } } \right) = \ln \left( {\left| {z^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } } \right|} \right) + i\arg \left( {z^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } } \right)
 = \ln {{\Gamma (z + k)} \over {\Gamma (z)}}
$$

The above tells us that your question is related to the absolute value and argument of the Gamma Function,
which unfortunately do not have a closed expression, better than the above.

Comment: I get the first and second steps but I don't understand what $\overline{k+1}$ and $\Gamma$ are. Could you please explain?

Comment: @ShreyJoshi From context I assume it's a strange factorial variant: $a^{\overline{b}} = (a+b)!/a!$?

Comment: Actually the third, fourth and fifth steps are not necessary. This can be derived directly from the definition of generalized binomial coefficients.

Comment: The Gamma function ($\Gamma (x)$) is the same as an offset factorial ($(x - 1)!$), but defined in such a way that it is usable for non-integer values of $x$. $i^{\,\overline {\,k + 1\,}}$ in this context is the rising factorial: $i(i + 1)(i + 2) \cdots (i + k - 1)(i + k)$.

Comment: @above, thank you for clearing it all up, I see how it fits together much better now. One thing I find funny is how we can define factorials and choose functions for imaginary numbers. It would also be interesting to see what would happen for fractional $k$.

Comment: But it still feels like cheating, expanding the choose function yields the same as the product of $(n+i)$. What I'm looking for is a closed form solution which reduces computation.

Comment: @ShreyJoshi: added some more details, wishing they are enough. Concerning the ".. solution which reduces computation" , since the Gamma Function computation algorithm is quite available in many platforms, please be more specific on what you are looking for.

Comment: @user7530: it is a common way to designate the Rising Factorial (also called Pochhammer symbol. See the added details

Comment: @ShreyJoshi: the Gamma Function allows for such an extension, where both the upper and lower terms of the binomial coefficient can be not only fractional, but real and even complex! (except for negative integers). For your curiosity $\binom{1}{1/2}=4/ \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that [the addition formula for the arctangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions) gives $\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)=\arctan(\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy})$; thus, if we define $\alpha_n$ by $\arctan(\alpha_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n\arctan(\frac1i)$, then we have $\alpha_n=\dfrac{\alpha_{n-1}+\frac1n}{1-\frac{\alpha_{n-1}}{n}}$ $=\dfrac{n\alpha_{n-1}+1}{n-\alpha_{n-1}}$; alternately, setting $\alpha_n=\frac{a_n}{b_n}$, we can write this as $a_n=na_{n-1}+b_{n-1}, b_n = -a_{n-1}+nb_{n-1}$ - or $\begin{pmatrix}a_n \\ b_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}n & 1 \\ -1 & n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_{n-1} \\ b_{n-1} \end{pmatrix}$.  This 'blows up' at $n=3$ (since there's a division by zero), but because the equation in terms of $a_n$ and $b_n$ is homogeneous, we can continue through that point with a rescaling: $(a_n, b_n) (1\leq n\leq 3) =\langle(1, 1), (3, 1), (10, 0)\rangle$, and rescaling to take $a_3=1, b_3=0$ we get $a_4=4, b_4=-1$; $a_5=19, b_5=-9$; $a_6=105, b_6=-73$; $a_7=662, b_7=-616$; etc. Unfortunately, I also can't find any references to this series, and the OEIS doesn't seem to be any help.