# Evaluating $\sum_{r=1}^n \arctan{(r)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, complex-numbers, inverse-function, trigonometric-series

> This is a question that my friend gave me
>   $$ \sum_{r=1}^n \arctan{(r)}$$

He also told me it is a very typical question different from regular arctan questions which are solved mostly using telescoping series. He gave me a hint that it involves complex numbers.

Now, I can relate that it has to do with the argument of a complex number defined by :
$$ \ z_r = 1 + ri $$
 If we take product of all such $z$ and take its argument, then we may find the sum
$$ \operatorname{Arg} \left[\prod_{r=1}^n z_r \right]$$
But I am then getting stuck in another unsolvable series.

Please help.

Comment: In complex Planet the $\arctan$ has definition: $$\arctan{z}=\frac{i}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{z-i}{z+i}\right)}$$Does this help?

Comment: Have you tried using the arc sum formula $$\arctan x+\arctan y=\arctan\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$$ and see whether the series becomes telescopic?

Comment: @metamorphy That's not a hint. It's a suggestion of what to *try.* If it were a *hint,* I'd have posted it as an answer. Good day!

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\tan$ using `\tan`. For operators like $\operatorname{Arg}$ that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{Arg}`.

Comment: There is such a technique, and some series with $\arctan$ can be summed by it, see [Sums of arctangents and some formulas of Ramanujan by Boros-Moll, p.18](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.233.540&rep=rep1&type=pdf). But not this one, there is no closed formula for it.

Comment: @Allawonder as i wrote in the desription that arc sum formula is usually used but its not fitting in here

Comment: @Sewer Keeper can you please post the expression of your comment simply in normal text , its unreadable

Comment: Say we prove by induction a formula for $\tan(\sum_{r=1}^n\arctan r)$. There's still a problem determining the sum,$$\frac{\pi}{4}+\sum_{r=2}^n\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\frac1r\right)=\frac{\pi(2n-1)}{4}-\sum_{r=2}^n\arctan\frac1r.$$The subtracted sum is asymptotic to $H_n\sim\ln n$ for large $n$, so being precise about which range of the form $((k-\tfrac12)\pi,\,(k+\tfrac12)\pi],\,k\in\Bbb N$ contains it is tricky for large $n$.

Comment: "A friend asked me" is a very typical story we read here. I've always wondered why people ask me how to solve it, then, and not that friend.

Answer (score 1):

From comment of [user: J.G](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/56861/j-g) and from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2856119/geometry-problem-boils-down-to-finding-a-closed-form-for-sum-n-1k-arctan/2856351#2856351) we have:

$$\sum_{r=1}^n \arctan{(r)}=\frac{n \pi }{2}-\Im\left(\ln \left(\frac{\Gamma ((1+i)+n)}{\Gamma (1+i)}\right)\right)$$