# $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \arctan(k)=? $ Using argument of complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, trigonometric-series

Question:
\begin{align} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \arctan(k)=? \end{align}

My approach:

\begin{align} \prod_{k=1}^{n} (1+ik)=a+ib\qquad(1)\end{align}
\begin{align} \Rightarrow arg \Bigg(\prod_{k=1}^{n} (1+ik)\Bigg) =arg \Big(a+bi\Big) \end{align}
\begin{align} \Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{n} \arctan(k) =arg \Big(a+bi\Big) \end{align}

I am stuck here because $ (1) $ is too big to solve by hand and get $ a,b $ . Can anyone help find it out? Also I have a kinda similar problem that I have faced when tried it to solve by hand and get $ a,b $. Here's the link [Sum of $ ^nC_k $ terms from $ n $ numbers and each term having $ k $ numbers multiplied .](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4450191/1027837)

Comment: This doesn't make sense because the argument is not a linear function. What you really want to consider is the product $\prod_{k=1}^n (1+ik)$

Comment: If your problem requires numerical calculation of argument and not analytical solution, you can change $1+i k$ to $\frac1k+i$ which has the same argument. But argument is multiple-valued function so $\sum_{k=1}^n\arctan(k)=\arg(a+bi)+2\pi m$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3635087/815585 Not a pleasant closed form